# Field that links to a path/url defined with Tokens, is it possible?

Tags: entities, navigation, tokens

I would like to create a few fields in a content type that will link to certain paths defined with Tokens, in my particular case the node author uid. I am using a number of user related modules including Flag, User Relationships, Heartbeat etc which define user specific paths for a number of tasks that users can do (eg. view their flagged content, manage their relationsships etc). Hence my need to use Tokens to define the paths as oppose to just writing the static path myself. The paths would need to be auto generated for each node based on the Tokens, like Pathauto except for field links.

The [Link module](http://drupal.org/project/link) would be perfect for this, but in my experience, it does not fully support Tokens for the url. Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Link field module DOES support tokens in Drupal 7, both in the link title and the link url field. You might be confused by the fact that the token drop down menu is at the top of the link edit form so it looks like it's not for the url field at the bottom of the page. I was confused by this before myself. Also make sure you have the right input field focused on first before you start clicking to add tokens.

Comment: Aah, you're right. I did see the token menu but when I clicked the tokens but it was only going into the fields above. Novice mistake! Thanks a lot for that.