# Create send user private message link in a node template content type

Tags: privatemsg

How do you print the private message link in a node template please?

This what I've tried

```
hide($content['field_privatemsg']);

print render($content['field_privatemsg']);
```

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to create a link to the author, you should be able to create a simple link in the template
 - [Field that links to a path/url defined with Tokens, is it possible?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40582/field-that-links-to-a-path-url-defined-with-tokens-is-it-possible)

It would follow something like: http://www.example.com/messages/new/[node:author]

You can see a list of tokens here: https://drupal.org/node/390482#token-node